# Partially specialize a template on the the first parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I tried to do something today that I was surprised to realize didn't work. I have a template that takes a type and a value as parameters. I want to specialize on the type parameter, but leave the value parameter open. Like so

```
template <class T = void, bool Enabled = false>
struct seFoo {};

template <bool Enabled>
struct seFoo<int, Enabled> {};

// Doesn't work :(
seFoo<false> foo;
```

However, this leads to a compile error for too few template arguments. It appears the instantiation has to match the signature of the unspecialized template before the compiler will even look at the partial specialization.

Is there a way to get this to work?

If this approach fundamentally isn't possibly, I'm interested in alternative approaches.

Apparently I'm not the only one surprised by this. [This article](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) makes the same mistake towards the end.

Comment: partially specializing doesn't make these template arguments optional. You still have to pass both when you use the template.

Comment: So you want both `seFoo<int, false>` to use a different class definition from the primary, and also a shorter way to type `seFoo<int, false>`? Is it okay if the shorter way uses a different name?

Comment: I'm actually trying to get both `seFoo<int>` and `seFoo<false>` to work.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't really do this.

Note that a class template partial specialization is not something you can use directly in any way.  Its only function is that when you to attempt to use the primary template as normal, if the partial specialization is a match for your template arguments and is the best match among any other explicit / partial specializations, then the partial specialization is used instead of the primary template to generate the definition of that particular class type.

In some cases there are things you can do with default template arguments, defining your own meanings for template arguments, or other such tricks.  But there's no way to have one template that can take either a type or a value as its first template argument, and you can't have two class templates or alias templates with the same name in the same scope.